# using a pointer to vector<T>::data() for cublasSgemm

Tags: c++, pointers, vector, cuda, cublas

I am trying to use the vector::data() pointer when using cudaMalloc, cudaMemcpy, and cublasSgemm but I can't seem to get it to work. If I am not mistaken, vector::data() should return a pointer to the actual array stored in memory for that vector so it should be the same as having a T* aArray pointer to an array of type T stored in memory. Using the latter does work, but not the data() pointer.

Here is the code I am working on:

```
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::cudaProd(Matrix<T>&A,Matrix<T>&B, Matrix<T>&C)
{
C = Matrix<T>(A.height, B.width); //resizing of the vector of elements for Matrix C
//A[m][n]*B[n][k]=C[m][k]
int m = A.height;
int n = B.height;
int k = B.width;
float alpha = 1.0f;
float beta = 0.0f;

T* d_a = A.GetPointer();
T* d_b = B.GetPointer();
T* d_c = C.GetPointer();

cudaMalloc(&d_a,A.size);
cudaMalloc(&d_b,B.size);
cudaMalloc(&d_c,C.size);

cudaMemcpy(d_a,A.GetPointer(),A.size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b,B.GetPointer(),B.size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cublasHandle_t handle;

cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&handle);

if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
{
    std::cerr << "!!!! CUBLAS initialization error\n";
}

status = cublasSgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,k,m,n,&alpha,d_b,k,d_a,n,&beta,d_c,k);

if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
{
    std::cerr << "!!!! kernel execution error.\n";
}

status = cublasDestroy(handle);
if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
{
    std::cerr << "!!!! shutdown error (A)\n";
}

cudaMemcpy(C.GetPointer(), d_c, C.size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(d_a);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_c);
```

The GetPointer() member function returns vector::data() of the vector of elements for that Matrix object. Size is the vector element's size in memory.

The vector of Matrix C returns all zeros when using the data() pointer, and returns the product of Matrix A and B when using T* aArray pointers without vectors.

Is it actually possible to use vectors to store the array of elements and then the data() pointer to initialize the device copy of the array, or am I forced to use the C style array storage on the host? Also, I have tried using thrust::device_vector and that works but I would like to stay away from creating raw_pointer_casts.

Thanks for your help!

Edit:
 For those having trouble with copy and pasting, here is the complete example:

```
#include <cuda.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include <cuda_device_runtime_api.h>
#include <cublas_v2.h>
#include <vector>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

template<typename T> class Matrix
{
public:
~Matrix();
Matrix();
Matrix(int rows, int columns);
int width;
int height;
int stride;
size_t size;

T &GetElement(int row, int column);
void SetElement(int row, int column, T value);
void SetElements(vector<T> value);
vector<T>& GetElements();
T* GetPointer();
Matrix<T> cudaProd(Matrix<T>&A,Matrix<T>&B, Matrix<T>&C);
private:
vector<T> elements;
T* firstElement;
};

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::~Matrix()
{
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix()
{
}

template<typename T>
Matrix<T>::Matrix(int rows, int columns)
{
height = rows;
width = columns;
stride = columns; //in row major order this is equal to the # of columns
elements.resize(rows*columns);
firstElement = elements.data();
size = height*width*sizeof(T);
}

template<typename T>
T &Matrix<T>::GetElement(int row, int column)
{
return elements[row*width + column]; //row major order return
}

template<typename T>
vector<T>& Matrix<T>::GetElements()
{
return elements; //row major order return
}

template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::SetElement(int row, int column, T value)
{
elements[row*width + column] = value; //row major order return
}

template<typename T>
void Matrix<T>::SetElements(vector<T> value)
{
elements = value;
}

template<typename T>
T* Matrix<T>::GetPointer()
{
return firstElement;
}


template<typename T>
//Matrix Multiplication using CUDA
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::cudaProd(Matrix<T>&A,Matrix<T>&B, Matrix<T>&C)
{
C = Matrix<T>(A.height, B.width);
//A[m][n]*B[n][k]=C[m][k]
int m = A.height;
int n = B.height;
int k = B.width;
float alpha = 1.0f;
float beta = 0.0f;


//Thrust usage

/*thrust::device_vector<T> d_A = A.GetElements();
T* d_a = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_A[0]);
thrust::device_vector<T> d_B = B.GetElements();
T* d_b = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_B[0]);
thrust::device_vector<T> d_C = C.GetElements();
T* d_c = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&d_C[0]);*/

T* d_a = A.GetPointer();
T* d_b = B.GetPointer();
T* d_c = C.GetPointer();

cudaMalloc(&d_a,A.size);
cudaMalloc(&d_b,B.size);
cudaMalloc(&d_c,C.size);

cudaMemcpy(d_a,A.GetPointer(),A.size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_b,B.GetPointer(),B.size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
cudaMemcpy(d_c,C.GetPointer(),C.size,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

cublasHandle_t handle;

cublasStatus_t status = cublasCreate(&handle);

if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
{
    std::cerr << "!!!! CUBLAS initialization error\n";
}

status = cublasSgemm(handle,CUBLAS_OP_N,CUBLAS_OP_N,k,m,n,&alpha,d_b,k,d_a,n,&beta,d_c,k);

if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
{
    std::cerr << "!!!! kernel execution error.\n";
}

status = cublasDestroy(handle);
if (status != CUBLAS_STATUS_SUCCESS) 
{
    std::cerr << "!!!! shutdown error (A)\n";
}

//thrust::copy(d_C.begin(), d_C.end(), C.GetElements().begin());

cudaMemcpy(C.GetPointer(), d_c, C.size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

cudaFree(d_a);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_c);

return C;

}

int main()
{
    Matrix<float> A(2,2);
Matrix<float> B(2,2);
Matrix<float> C;

vector<float> aE(4,2);
vector<float> bE(4,4);
A.SetElements(aE);
B.SetElements(bE);

C = C.cudaProd(A, B, C);  //function call to cudaProd()

for(int row = 0; row < A.height; ++row)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < A.width; ++col)
    {       
        cout<<A.GetElement(row, col)<<" "; //h_c is stored on device in column major order, need to switch to row major order
     }
     printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");

for(int row = 0; row < B.height; ++row)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < B.width; ++col)
    {       
        cout<<B.GetElement(row, col)<<" "; //h_c is stored on device in column major order, need to switch to row major order
     }
     printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");

for(int row = 0; row < C.height; ++row)
{
    for(int col = 0; col < C.width; ++col)
    {       
        cout<<C.GetElement(row, col)<<" "; //h_c is stored on device in column major order, need to switch to row major order
     }
     printf("\n");
}
printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: I would suggest providing a short complete code that demonstrates the error. You can use vector as host data.

Comment: Ok I edited my question to include an example of what I am trying to explain. Let me know if its still confusing

Comment: Be warned that the size method you are using in cudaMemcpy should return the size in bytes, not the length of the vector. Also, please provide a code that could be copied and pasted, compiled and run, instead of pieces of code.

Comment: The size  does return the size in bytes: size = height*width*sizeof(T); Also, you should be able to run the simple example in the int main(void) with the code that I provided. The only member functions I didn't provide are the GetPointer() and GetElements(). GetPointer() returns T* firstElement(its in the constructor for Matrix<T>() ), and GetElements() returns vector<T> elements.

Comment: @user3390212: The code you have posted cannot be compiled. Please edit your question to include something someone else could compile and run.

Comment: Ok, edited the question and put all the code I had posted, literally copy and pasted from here to VS, and put it into one convenient copy and paste. You should not have had any trouble compiling if you compiled with the proper cuda header files and set your build to compile with cuda.

Comment: @user3390212: There was no definition of the matrix class anywhere, only its constructor. That is why the code could not be compiled.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [std::vector::data documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/data/), `data()` returns both `const` and non-`const` qualified pointers, depending on the fact that the `vector` is qualified as `const` or not. Quoting the documentation

> If the vector object is const-qualified, the function returns a pointer to const value_type. Otherwise, it returns a pointer to value_type.

Accordingly, using

```
firstElement = elements.data();
```

in the `Matrix` constructor is fine to read/write the data.

The main problem with your code is that you are declaring `C` in the `main`, passing a reference to `C` to the `cudaProd` method and then internally using

```
C = Matrix<T>(A.height, B.width);
```

which will redeclare the `Matrix`.

If you change the definition of the `cudaProd` method to

```
template<typename T>
void cudaProd(Matrix<T>&A,Matrix<T>&B, Matrix<T>&C)
```

remove the

```
return C;
```

statement and allocate space for `C` in the main as

```
Matrix<float> C(2,2);
vector<float> cE(4,10);
C.SetElements(cE);
```

your code should work correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> If I am not mistaken, `vector::data()` should return a pointer to the actual array stored in memory for that vector so it should be the same as having a `T*` aArray pointer to an array of type `T` stored in memory.

The `std::vector` class is an *owning* resource class. It means that trying to manage the underlying resource yourself with the `data` pointer will make you enter a world of pain.

For this very same reason:

```
cudaMalloc(&d_a,A.size);
cudaMalloc(&d_b,B.size);
cudaMalloc(&d_c,C.size);
```

and:

```
cudaMemcpy(C.GetPointer(), d_c, C.size,cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
```

and:

```
cudaFree(d_a);
cudaFree(d_b);
cudaFree(d_c);
```

cannot possibly work.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying that. This is most likely why I am getting zeros as answers.

Comment: Initializing `const T* d_a = A.GetPointer();` just before `cudaMalloc(&d_a,A.size);` is meaningless, since the memory location pointed to by `d_a` is device memory location, while that pointed to by `A.GetPointer()` is host memory location.

Comment: @user3390212 I'm not sure whether this answer is correct. Please, see my one.

Comment: @JackOLantern, Yeah, I forgot about the non-cost version, but freeing and reallocating the underlying resource of an `std::vector` is not correct.